# How can I create visual studio 2012 template from Office App template?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-templates

How can I create my custom visual studio template based on Office App template?

Answer (score 0):

You can locate the Office Add-in templates in the following directory, then you modify the template as you see fit and then put them in your own template folder.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Office\Addins\1033

The template for the Visual Studio App for Office is located in the following directory:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\CSharp\Office SharePoint\Apps\1033\SharePoint15OfficeApp

Comment: It's directory for Office Add-ins but not Apps. Could you please provide the directory of Office Apps templates.